# Adding seasonality and non-stationarity to final result after ARIMA or ETS forecasting

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

```
TS<-ts(Product_Dist_Training_Trans[,17], frequency = 7)

plot(TS)
library(tseries)
library(forecast)

TSETS<- TS

adf<- adf.test(TS)

Order<- ndiffs(TS)

if (adf$p.value>.05)
{
for(i in  1:Order){
TSDiff<- diff(TS)  
TS<- TSDiff}} else
{
TS
}

decomp<- decompose(TS)

TSadj<- TS-decomp$seasonal

Arima<- auto.arima(TSadj)
AM<- forecast(Arima, h = 29)
AM$mean
plot(AM)

ETS<- ets(TSETS)
fc <- forecast(ETS, h = 29)
fc$mean
plot(fc)
```

I am trying to forecast daily sales quantity for 29 days with a  training data of 118 days, I am using both ARIMA and ETS forecasting. I am getting negative values in the final result for ARIMA (as I am making the series stationary and non-seasonal for ARIMA) as well as ETS, How do I get the correct forecast values in the final result? Also how should I make a comparison b/w the two methods so as to get more accurate results?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have defined time series object with frequency = 7 that means you are defining weekly seasonality of the data

For forecasting of time series with arima use the following code:

```
TS<-ts(Product_Dist_Training_Trans[,17], frequency = 7)
plot(TS)
library(tseries)
library(forecast)

decomp<-stl(TS , s.window = "periodic") 
plot(decomp)
decomp_components<-as.data.frame(decomp$time.series)

seasonal_component<-ts(decomp_components$seasonal, frequency = 7)

relation1<-auto.arima(seasonal_component,seasonal = T ,max.p = 10, max.q = 10, max.d = 5, max.P = 5, max.Q = 5, max.D = 2, max.order = 30, start.p = 1, start.q = 1)
result1<-forecast(relation1, model = "Arima", h = 29)

plot(result1)
deseasonal_cnt<-seasadj(decomp)
relation2 <- auto.arima(deseasonal_cnt,seasonal = F ,max.p = 10, max.q = 10, max.d = 5,max.P = 5, max.Q = 5, max.D = 2, max.order = 30, start.p = 1, start.q = 1)

result2<-forecast(relation2, model = "Arima",h=29)
plot(result2)
result<-result1$mean+result2$mean
```

If this still gives you the negative values that means the trend component is decreasing so to avoid negative values, put zero instead

```
result[result<0]<- 0
```

The problem with your code is that you have forecasted only for the seasonal part, you also have to forecasting for the non seasonal part and then combine the result

Comment: Your code seems logical. Actually I have forecasted only for the non-seasonal part, as I am subtracting the seasonal component from the time series in                                  TSadj<- TS-decomp$seasonal, Could you please also help me with how to compare the ARIMA Model and ETS and find out which one is better.

Comment: ETS is used for exponential smoothing and smooth the outliers but ARIMA doesn't   so in my perspective ARIMA is better than ETS and if the data is very rough ETS is not able to handle it and give error while training but in ARIMA you can do whatever you want with the limitation of ensuring that 2 cycle +1 terms data should be provided to train the model otherwise ARIMA won't work. Learn also about prophet model its very easy with no limitation on feeding data.